# Function only returning first input of a list and not continuing in the input is outside a range

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I'm really new to coding (as in about 3 weeks in), and I'm writing a code where the user is asked to input a number between 0 and 100 and then this number is added to a list. Once the list reaches a length of 10 numbers, it should print the list. I'm using a function to this.

I can get it so it prints a list, but it's only printing the first number that is input. For example if I enter 5, it'll still ask for the other numbers, but it prints the list as [5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5]. Also if I enter a number outside the range of 0-100 it does ask you to input a different number, but then it stops and prints the list as 'None'.

Below is my code:

```
def getUser(n):
    mylist = []
    while 0 < n < 100:
        mylist.append(n)
        int(input("Please enter a number between 0 and 100: "))
        if len(mylist) == 10:
            return(mylist)
    else:
        int(input("This number is not in the range of 0-100, please input a different number: "))
    
    
n = int(input("Please enter a number between 0 and 100: "))
print("The numbers you have entered are: ", getUser(n))
```

I'm guessing its to do with the while/else loop but as I said I'm new to this and it all feels so overwhelming, and trying to google this just seems to bring about super complicated things that I don't understand!! Thanks

Comment: Why are you asking input again inside while loop and not using that / capturing in any variable ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First : Why you get  [5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5] :

```
int(input("Please enter a number between 0 and 100: "))
```

You should give this to n first :

```
n=int(input("Please enter a number between 0 and 100: "))
```

Then, it gets out of the loops because you go in the `else`, and then you don't go back in the `while`. Then your function ended, without `return`, so `none`

To be honest, I don't understand why your code gets out of the `while` loop if you give a number out of the range, as the value is not given to n. If someone could explain in comment, that would be great !

I would do it like that :

```py
def getUser():
    mylist = []
    while len(mylist) < 10:
        n = int(input("Please enter a number between 0 and 100: "))
        
        if (0 < n < 100):
            mylist.append(n)
        else:
            print('This is not between 0 and 100 !')

    return mylist
    
    
print("The numbers you have entered are: ", getUser())
```

Then you will be asked number from 0 to 100 (excluded) until you get a size of 10.

Comment: Incase OP can't tell, this is the best answer that's been provided so-far (Although I did want to encourage him to work his way up to something like this so he understands why this is the best answer & gets used to solving smaller problems with guidance instead of direct solutions so he's more comfortable with the larger/more difficult problems)

Comment: I think you solved it!! I think I just made it more confusing for myself but this was super simple and exactly what I needed. Thank you!!

Comment: @JackofSpades I understand - it's probably best for me to try and figure out how to do it myself with hints from others but I think this was OK since I understand each line of this code and why I'm using it. Coding is so hard!!

Answer (score 0):

So here's what you were doing wrong

```
def getUser(n):
    mylist = []
    while 0 < n < 100:
        mylist.append(n)
        n = int(input("Please enter a number between 0 and 100: "))
        if len(mylist) == 10:
            return(mylist)
    else:
        int(input("This number is not in the range of 0-100, please input a different number: "))
    
    
n = int(input("Please enter a number between 0 and 100: "))
print("The numbers you have entered are: ", getUser(n))
```

You notice any difference in the edited code?

You were never re-assigning the value of the variable `n`
So you would just add whatever value you passed to `getUser` every time (and it would be the same value every time)

Don't be afraid to ask for help if you're stuck!

P.S.
You can also move a line somewhere to somewhere else to make it behave a bit better if you're up to the challenge ;)

Comment: One should probably also address that the `else:` case would cause the entire function to end, which is probably not what was intended, based on the text in the `input` of the `else:`.
The entire `while` loop should probably be replaced by an `if`, wrapped in a `while True:`.

Comment: Yup! A hint for one way to solve that for OP is you could make `mylist` an argument with a default value and simply remove a line :)

Comment: There are big pitfalls with using default arguments, I have to warn you. In python, default arguments other than `None` are strongly discouraged.

Comment: Really? I don't think I use any default arguments other than None, but would you mind linking me to a resource that elaborates more on that?

Comment: It's very counter intuitive because python default arguments work a lot different than in almost any other language. I also disagree with the design decision of python here, but that's what we have to live with I guess.

Comment: ahhh, I think that's because of this behavior
```x=[] ; y = x ; y.append('test') ; print(x) ; > ['test'] ```

If I understand correctly, when you create a list variable that's assigned to an existing list variable, they both reference the same object/address in memory, so they both share the same values. I believe you would do something like this to create an actual copy of the list with their own seperate memory space

`x = [1,2,3] ; y = x[:] ; y.append(4) ; print(x)`

iirc that should work to create a copy

Comment: Yes and no, it's correct that they all share one instance, but the fix would be to have the default argument be `None` and then in the next line do `if x is None: x = []`. That way you get separate lists every time.

Comment: For the problem OP would want to address, you are correct, I was simply ranting about pythons typically unexpected behavior with reassigning a list variable to a new variable and a possible solution on how to address it, since OP might encounter that one day and start scratching his head wondering what went wrong (although he'd probably just make another post about it)

Answer (score 0):

```
def getUser(n):
mylist = []
t = True
while t:
    n =int(input("Please enter a number between 0 and 100: "))
    if n >0 and n<=100:
        mylist.append(n)
    if len(mylist) == 10:
        return(mylist)
        t = False
    elif n < 0  or n >100:
        print('This number is not in the range of 0-100, please input a different number:')
```

Comment: That should work, but you don't need any argument, and the t = False is useless, as you already returned. And I don't really like returning during a loop, but that's totally personal.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, you are trying to use `while` instead of `if`.
Here is what I would do - I will explain it soon:

```py
def get_user():
    mylist = []
    for i in range(5):
        n = int(input("Please enter a number between 0 and 100: "))
        if n <= 100 and 0 <= n:
            mylist.append(n)
            
        else:
            print("This is not between 0 and 100 !")
            i = i - 1

    return mylist
```

#### Going through the code

`for i in range(5)`

Here we use the `for` to iterate through a `range`
of numbers (0 - 5). `for` will assign `i` to the smallest
number in the range and constantly add 1 to `i` every iteration until
`i` is out of the `range`. See [this](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=range#range) for more info on `range`

`if n <= 100 and 0 <= n:`

Here `and` checks if **2** expressions are true.
In this case, if n is less than or equal to hundred and more than or equal to 0.
You could use `and` any number of times you want like this:

```py
if 1 < 100 and 100 > 200 and 20 < 40:
   print("foo!")
```

Now look at the `else` :

```
else:
    i = i - 1
```

Here, we subtract 1 from `i` and thus, decreasing our progress by one.
Also note that my function is called `get_user()` and not `getUser()`.
In python, we use snake case and not camel case.

I hope this answer helps. I have given small hints in my answer.
You should google them! I also am not directly giving you the logic.
Try to figure it out! That way you would have a good understanding of what I did.

Comment: Why would you decriment n? This is misleading to OP

Comment: @JackofSpades I uh, made a typo. I meant `i = i - 1`. I agree that `n = n - 1` makes no sense. I have updated the answer

Comment: `for i in range(10): print(i) if i == 7: i = i -1`
Try running that code in your interpreter. changing the value of `i` does not affect the for-loop's behavior.

This code is misleading to OP.

Comment: The reason for this is because `i` is reassigned to the next iteration of `range(10)` effectively rendering the decrementing of `i` useless